# ItemsControl Not Creating ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

Why isn't my ItemsControl creating a ContentPresenter for each item? I'm guessing this is what's making my items not show up (they're set to visible and in the right spot when I inspect using the Live Visual Tree). I'm basically reusing code that works up above in a different ItemsControl and I haven't been able to find anything while searching Google/Stackoverflow with this issue. I can include view model code but I don't think it's related because I see the appropriate values in the Live Property Explorer and can see each WellContainer is in it's appropriate grid cell.

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Wells}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid
                x:Name="m_WellGrid"
                Margin="5"
                wpf:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                wpf:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}">
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter
                Property="Grid.Row"
                Value="{Binding Path=WellRow}"/>
            <Setter
                Property="Grid.Column"
                Value="{Binding Path=WellCol}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="A"
                Margin="4"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Live Visual Tree Inspection:

[image]

Comment: Where is `WellContainer` defined? Are you explicitly defining a `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: My view model has an `ObservableCollection` of `WellContainer`s and `WellContainer` is just a class in the same project which inherits from `Control`. No, I'm not explicitly defining a `ContentPresenter` just the `DataTemplate` as this is what I've done in the two other cases that seem to work nearby.

Comment: If your content is there and in the right spot like you say, check the `Z-Index` and make sure it's not just hidden behind something

Comment: `ZIndex` on the problematic grid is 0 the same as the two grids that work and there really shouldn't be anything else there. `Opacity` is 1 and every property looks great except the grid never shows/renders :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsControl` is designed to wrap the items in a container only when necessary, that is, when the item is not eligible to be its own container. From your comment we find that `WellContainer` derives from `Control`, thus is eligible to be its own container<sup>*1*</sup> and is not wrapped in a `ContentPresenter`. Unfortunately there's no way to control this behavior directly, but you could subclass `ItemsControl` and override the [`ItemsControl.IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.isitemitsowncontaineroverride(v=vs.110).aspx) method to modify the default behavior.

---

*<sup>1</sup> As we can see in the `ItemsControl` [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,25566aa6db31bf29) it is enough for the item to be of `UIElement` type to be eligible to be its own container.*

Comment: As a note, having a collection of controls in the view model is a bad idea. You wouldn't be able to display them in more than one ItemsControl at the same time, because a UI element can only have one parent, i.e. not be the child of multiple parent elements.

Comment: Ok makes sense, thank you. I'll try to come up with a solution and update the question.